# Angular.js request/response Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angularjs, request

---

I am trying to request some data from node.js server from my angular.js. The problem is that upon data response i see a blank browser window with my json object printed on it. I want angular.js to recognize the response and stay on page.

HTML form - template that gets loaded with loginController

```
<section class="small-container">
    <div class="login-form">
        <form action="/login" method="post" ng-submit="processForm()">
            <input ng-model="formData.username" type="text" name="username">
            <input ng-model="formData.password" type="password" name="password">
            <button>login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Angular.JS

```
var app = angular.module("blavor", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "/index",
            controller: "loginController"
        })
        .when("/register", {
            templateUrl: "/register",
            controller: "registerController"
        })
        .otherwise("/");

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.processForm = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/login',
            data: $.param($scope.formData),
            processData: false, 
            responseType: "json",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (!data.success) {
                    alert("Noo!");
                } else {
                    alert("YEEEY!");
                }
            });
    };
});
```

Node.js Server - index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var express = require('express');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }) );
var routes = require('./routes')(app);
http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

module.exports.start = start;

Node.js Server - routes

```
module.exports = function(app) {
app.post('/login', function(request, response) {
console.log(request.body);
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    response.end(JSON.stringify({value:"somevalue"}));
});
}
```

I am using  AngularJS v1.2.24 and Node.js v0.10.25

console.log(data) in angular never gets called..

Comment: Is a form being submitted? did you call preventDefault on the event?

Comment: Form is being submitted. Server returns request.body or anything else I put in JSON.stringify but Angular.js never gets a chance to see it, because page refreshes and displays only json from response. LIke some kind of redirect happens from node.js part..

Comment: @anish Yes it is express

Comment: @DusanJ. can you post up the form code? Probably would be good to include the relevant route handling code from express for requests to /login

Comment: @Gabs00 Yes. I think the way I used express is really bad.

Comment: @DusanJ. you should remove the action and method from your form. you may need $event.preventDefault inside of the processForms function as well. try removing action and method first.

Comment: @Gabs00 I removed action and method and it works. Thanks a million! We've lost 6-7 hours on this. ХВАЛА!

Comment: @DusanJ. fyi I added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try removing the `action` and `method` from your form.

From the ng-submit docs

> Enables binding angular expressions to onsubmit events.
>
> Additionally it prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page), but only if the form does not contain action, data-action, or x-action attributes.

So by adding those, you are causing the page to refresh when the form is submitted.

Without them, angular will call $event.preventDefault() for you, which stops the page from being reloaded.

EDIT: Just to add, you were seeing the correct data from the server because you're responding with preset data, which will always be provided when someone posts to /login.

So your form is currently circumventing angular entirely, and directly getting the data from the server.